# Странное поведения реакта при overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, create-react-app

Люди добрые помогите, уже уйму времени потратил на решение этой проблемы, но не могу понять почему происходит такое поведение. Эта плашка и если на нее навести то она плавно раскрывается.

```
 &__item {
    height: 470px;
    &-layout {
      background: #fff;
      box-shadow: 5px 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
      padding: 37px 39px 36px;
      max-height: 327px;
      overflow: hidden;
      color: $main-color;
      @include transition(max-height .6s);
      border-radius: 15px;
      &:hover {
        max-height: 470px;
      }
    }
 }
 &__button {
    margin-top: 87px;
    background: linear-gradient(133.47deg, #5051C8 -22.37%, #A80DCD 91.58%), #6D33B3;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 44px;

    &:hover {
      background: #a80ccd;
    }
  }
```

[image]
[image]

Проблема заключается в том что при открытие модального окна и после его закрытия контент внутри едет на верх, при этом если смотреть через консоль, то никаких для этого действия стилей не накладывается. Если снова навести на плашку, то она так же раскрывается и контент внутри встает на свое место и поведение восстанавливается, но открывая снова модалку, происходит то же самое. Если в стилях убрать overflow:hidden, то все будет нормально. Использую модал бутстрап, думал сначала что такое поведение из за него, писал модалку руками, но эффект тот же.

[image]

Компонент модалки

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal'
class Callback extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        show={this.props.show}
        onHide={this.props.onHide}
      >
        <Modal.Body>
          //Форма
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}
export default Callback
```

Компонент плашки

```
import React from 'react'
import ButtonCallback from "../../UI/ButtonCallback";
const ServiceItem = () => {
const items = [
    {title: 'Titile', coast: 'coast', description:'Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem'}
];

return (
  <div className="row">
   {items.map((item,index) => {
     return (
      <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-6 services__col" key={index}>
       <div className="services__item">
        <div className="services__item-layout">
          <div className="services__head">
            <h3 className="services__title-head">{item.title}</h3>
            <span className="services__coast">{item.coast}</span>
          </div>
          <p className="services__text">
          {item.description}
          </p>
          <ButtonCallback className="button services__button"/>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      )
    })}
  </div>
)
};
export default ServiceItem
```

Компонент кнопки

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Callback from './CallBack'

class ButtonCallback extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };
    this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
    this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this)
  }

  openModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: true
    });
    document.getElementById('page').style.filter = 'blur(3px)'

  };
  hideModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: false
    });
    document.getElementById('page').style.filter = 'none'
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button type="button"
                className={this.props.className}
                onClick={this.openModal}
        >
          Оставить заявку
        </button>
        <Callback
          show={this.state.isOpen}
          onHide={this.hideModal}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
export default ButtonCallback
```

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял, что когда мы наводим и вызываем модалку, то браузер не понимает что мы убрали мышку, с этими правками ниже можно увидеть что когда мы наведем и вызовем модалку, то по сути у нас должен сработать mouseLeave, но при закрытии модального окна плашка остается открытой, то есть mouseLeave не срабатывает, но это решает проблему сдвига контента вверх.

Ниже я решил свою проблему таким образом

Стили:

```
  &__item {
    height: 470px;
    &-layout {
      background: #fff;
      box-shadow: 5px 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
      padding: 37px 39px 36px;
      height: 327px;
      overflow: hidden;
      color: $main-color;
      @include transition(height .6s);
      border-radius: 15px;
      &.hover {
        height: 470px;
      }
    }
  }
```

Компонент плашки (ServicesItemHover сделан, чтобы класс hover выдавался только блоку на которого навели):

```
import React from 'react'
import ButtonCallback from "../../UI/ButtonCallback";
class ServicesItemHover extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isHovered: false
        };
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div
         {...this.props}
         onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({isHovered: true})}
         onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({isHovered: false})}
         className={"services__item-layout " + (this.state.isHovered ? 'hover' : '')}
         />
      )
    }
}
const ServiceItem = () => {
const items = [
    {title: 'Titile', coast: 'coast', description:'Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem'}
];

return (
  <div className="row">
   {items.map((item,index) => {
     return (
      <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-6 services__col" key={index}>
       <div className="services__item">
          <ServicesItemHover>
           <div className="services__head">
            <h3 className="services__title-head">{item.title}</h3>
            <span className="services__coast">{item.coast}</span>
           </div>
           <p className="services__text">
            {item.description}
           </p>
           <ButtonCallback className="button services__button"/>
          </ServicesItemHover>
        </div>
       </div>
      )
    })}
  </div>
)
};
export default ServiceItem
```